# after trying to clean failing package installiations desktop not loading anymore correctly

Tags: 20.04

[image]

I tried to remove error messages cause updating packages did not work. Now I cannot open a terminal anymore and cant click on anything anymore. But mouse and keyboard are otherwise still working.

What can I do? I have 20.04 lts installed

Comment: You have two options: You can provide detailed information about exactly what you did, or you can back up your data and reinstall.

Comment: thank you for your reply. can I expect all my personal data in the home directory? or are there other directories I should look into? (I am now just copying all files onto another external drive). I think I will reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: You can expect your personal data to be where you saved it.